# Summing columns without removing individual values

Tags: mysql, sum

I am a total novice and getting stuck.

I am working with an auction dataset, and trying to find

1. the amount each individual spent (currently 'individual_bid_amount'), as well as
2. the amount each group spent and
3. the amount overall spent.

So far I have inputted the following

```
SELECT bi.BidderID,
bi.GroupID,
b.BidAmount AS individual_bid_amount
FROM Bidder bi
JOIN Bids b ON bi.BidderID = b.BidderID
ORDER BY bi.GroupID;
```

and got the following result

| BidderId | GroupId | individual_bid_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 7 | 342 |
| 10 | 7 | 402 |
| 20 | 7 | 57 |
| 35 | 15 | 78 |
| 50 | 15 | 55 |
| 50 | 15 | 405 |
| 51 | 15 | 126 |
| 53 | 60 | 2300 |
| 53 | 60 | 50 |
| 57 | 60 | 196 |
| 60 | 60 | 55 |

To get the overall total, I think I SHOULD use `SUM(b.BidAmount)` before the `FROM` but when I do this, it only returns one row, which includes the overall bid amount - but I am supposed to be able to present the answers to all three questions on one query.

Question 2, which requires me to sum up bids within each group, I am totally flummoxed on.

Comment: For these sort of questions you should be showing your table layour and architecture in the question, as well as your intended result. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do a SELECT subquery with your SUM and WHERE criteria within it. `SELECT a,b,c,... , (SELECT SUM(column) FROM table WHERE inner_sum_condition) AS sum_value WHERE outer_conditional` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` with the [ROLLUP modifier](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT 
  bi.GroupID,
  bi.BidderID,
  SUM(b.BidAmount) AS individual_bid_amount
FROM Bidder bi
JOIN Bids b ON bi.BidderID = b.BidderID
GROUP BY bi.GroupID, bi.BidderID WITH ROLLUP
```

The result would look like this:

| GroupID | BidderID | bid_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 8 | 342 |
| 7 | 10 | 402 |
| 7 | 20 | 57 |
| 7 | NULL | 801 |
| 15 | 35 | 78 |
| 15 | 50 | 460 |
| 15 | 51 | 126 |
| 15 | NULL | 664 |
| 60 | 53 | 2350 |
| 60 | 57 | 196 |
| 60 | 60 | 55 |
| 60 | NULL | 2601 |
| NULL | NULL | 4066 |